# SQL Help: How do count by a group, when a date is updated?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, tableau-api

Percona MySql 5.6, linux x64.

We have a `customers_history` table, which tracks changes to our customers over time. What we would like to do is count the changes by vendor(lead_source_id) over the course of a particular month.

```
+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+--------+
| id     | customer_id | lead_source_id |   repurchased_date  | Rating |
+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+--------+
| 422923 |      420450 |              4 | 2014-04-14 09:16:48 |   Warm |
| 422924 |      420450 |              4 | 2014-04-14 09:16:48 |   Cold |
| 422956 |      420450 |              4 | 2014-04-14 09:16:49 |    Hot |
| 422933 |      420451 |             37 | 2014-04-14 09:18:41 |    Hot |
| 422938 |      420452 |              1 | 2014-04-10 20:50:30 |    Hot |
| 422984 |      420452 |              1 | 2014-04-12 20:50:30 |    Hot |
| 422940 |      420453 |             47 | 2014-04-14 09:20:27 |    Hot |
+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Given the above sample, what we would like is this report, which reports repurchases by vendor(lead_source_id). What qualifies as a repurchase is when the repurchase_date is updated. Only changing the rating does not count.

```
+----------------+-------+
| lead_source_id | count |
+----------------+-------+
|              4 |     2 |
|             37 |     1 |
|              1 |     2 |
|             47 |     1 |
+----------------+-------+
```

We tried this initially:

`SELECT count(DISTINCT(ch.repurchased_date))
FROM   customers_history ch
WHERE  Year(ch.repurchased_date) = 2014
   AND Month(ch.repurchased_date) = 4
   AND ch.lead_source_id IS NOT NULL;`

But the count differs from the number of rows returned when you change the where clause to `SELECT DISTINCT(ch.created_at)), lead_source_id`.

Anyway, we're in a pickle jar trying to figure this out. Thanks a ton for any help or pointers.

## EDIT

CRAP. I'm sorry guys, thank you for the answers so far, but I totally left off why this problem is so danged hard. This is actually a history table, it records changes from multiple columns. I edited the original question.

Notice how the repurchased_date doesn't change when the rating changes. We would like to exclude row 422923 from the count, but count rows 422924 and 422956.

Comment: Hint "Group by(lead_sorce_id)"

Comment: Right, but if you group by lead_sorce_id, you must also group by cust_updated_at. Notice two rows have the same cust_updated_at, wouldn't that throw the answer off?

Comment: SELECT lead_sorce_id, COUNT(lead_sorce_id) FROM customers_history ch GROUP BY lead_sorce_id

Comment: I don't have the laptop right now, but I saw this kind of problems somewhere and a solution was to use the count wih the group by , already how - I can't tell, not much of a sql I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks real close. I'm thinking that all that's needed is to add a `GROUP BY` clause.

The `COUNT(DISTINCT foo)` will effectively "collapse" identical values, so that the count only gets incremented by 1 for each :group: of identical date values.

Based on the sample data, and the desired resultset, this should work:

```
 SELECT ch.lead_source_id
      , COUNT(DISTINCT ch.repurchased_date)
   FROM customers_history ch
  WHERE ch.repurchased_date >= '2014-04-01'
    AND ch.repurchased_date  < '2014-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    AND ch.lead_source_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP
     BY ch.lead_source_id
```

In the example data, the `customer_id` and the `lead_source_id` correlate with each other. (Could be due to a small sample size...)

(See NOTES below for additional comments regarding indexes, index range scans, and GROUP BY optimization using a covering index.)

---

**ANSWER BELOW PRIOR TO QUESTION UPDATE**

This is one way to return the specified result, except for the ordering, I wasn't able to discern a pattern...

```
SELECT ch.lead_source_id
     , COUNT(1) AS count_
  FROM customers_history ch
 WHERE ch.cust_updated_at >= '2014-04-01' 
   AND ch.cust_updated_at <  '2014-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND ch.lead_source_id IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY ch.lead_source_id
 ORDER BY ?
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the "count" to also be **by `cust_updated_at`**, include that column in the `GROUP BY`. For example, if for this sample data:

```
+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id     | customer_id | lead_source_id |   cust_updated_at   |
+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| 422924 |      420450 |              4 | 2014-04-14 09:16:48 |
| 422956 |      420450 |              4 | 2014-04-14 09:16:48 |
| ?????? |      420450 |              4 | 2014-04-15 22:22:22 |
+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

You want to return:

```
+----------------+-------+
| lead_source_id | count |
+----------------+-------+
|              4 |     2 |
|              4 |     1 |
+----------------+-------+
```

Then, add the **`cust_updated_at`** column to the **`GROUP BY`** clause, e.g.

```
SELECT ch.lead_source_id
     , COUNT(1) AS count_
  FROM customers_history ch
 WHERE ch.cust_updated_at >= '2014-04-01' 
   AND ch.cust_updated_at <  '2014-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND ch.lead_source_id IS NOT NULL
 GROUP
    BY ch.lead_source_id
     , ch.cust_updated_at
```

**NOTES:**

(If we leave off the `ORDER BY` clause, and the `GROUP BY` clause implicitly applies an `ORDER BY` on the same set of expressions. We only need to specify an `ORDER BY` clause to get a different ordering.)

Also, wrapping date columns in functions in a predicate prevents MySQL from satisfying the predicate by using an index range scan. We normally like to have "bare date columns" in the predicates, and do whatever manipulation is required on the constant side. (With the date column wrapped in a function, like `YEAR()` forces MySQL to evaluate that function for EVERY row in the table (or, every row that isn't filtered out by another predicate.)

For optimum performance, a suitable **covering index** for this query would be:

```
... ON customer_history (lead_source_id, created_at)
```

MySQL can satisfy the query entirely from the index; the explain output will show "Using index". If we leave off the ORDER BY clause, MySQL will avoid a "Using filesort" operation as well.

---

Comment: thanks for the info on the index scanning, didn't know that. See the updated question though, we realized we left something critical off.

Comment: @exabrial: I've looked at the updated question, and that is a little more tricky. If I'm understanding you, you want to exclude row 422923 from the count because the date column didn't change. That is, if there are multiple rows for the same `lead_source_id` with identical datetime values, you don't want to :count: the "duplicate" datetime rows. Just count that "group" of changes together as 1 change. (That explains the `COUNT(DISTINCT())` in the original query.)

Comment: "If I'm understanding you, you want to exclude row 422923 from the count because the date column didn't change" Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @exabrial: Answer updated, new answer is at the top. Your query was almost perfect. Using `COUNT(DISTINCT foo)` (similar to what you had in your original query), effectively "collapses" duplicates so that each :group: increments the count. Just need to add GROUP BY clause. Note that `DISTINCT` is a keyword. It's not a function, so there's no need to wrap "foo" in parens.

Comment: There isn't a correlation between lead source and customer, that was a fluke of the sample... doesn't appear that should make a difference though. I'll give this a try in a bit, thanks!

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept, I think this is the right answer. I did notice that I had an error in my data. Originally lead_source_id=1 should have only counted 1, not 2, so I edited a date to make it count to two.

Comment: If you don't mind, we have a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112039/sql-help-how-come-the-total-from-this-query-is-different-that-a-summation-query

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got what you're asking.
however do you mean this?

```
SELECT ch.lead_source_id, count(*)
FROM customers_history ch
WHERE
     Year(ch.created_at) = 2014 AND
     Month(ch.created_at) = 4 AND ch.lead_source_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ch.lead_source_id;
```