# SQL Help: How come the total from this query is different that a summation query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, tableau-api

This query does a group by on lead_source_id:

```
SELECT ch.lead_source_id,
       Count(DISTINCT ch.repurchased_date)
FROM   customers_history ch
WHERE  ch.repurchased_date >= '2014-04-01'
   AND ch.repurchased_date < '2014-05-01'
   AND ch.lead_source_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY ch.lead_source_id;
```

And this query totals the records in the table:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT( repurchased_date ))
FROM   customers_history
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT( customer_id ) AS xcid
                   FROM   customers_history
                   WHERE  repurchased_date >= '2014-04-01'
                      AND repurchased_date < '2014-05-01'
                      AND lead_source_id IS NOT NULL) AS Temp
               ON Temp.xcid = customer_id
WHERE  repurchased_date >= '2014-04-01'
   AND repurchased_date < '2014-05-01'
   AND lead_source_id IS NOT NULL;
```

On our production data, the totals from Query1 come to 7963, but the second query prints 7905. Why the difference and how can we fix our queries?

Here's our table layout:

```
+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+--------+
| id     | customer_id | lead_source_id |   repurchased_date  | Rating |
+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+--------+
| 422923 |      420450 |              4 | 2014-04-14 09:16:48 |   Warm |
| 422924 |      420450 |              4 | 2014-04-14 09:16:48 |   Cold |
| 422956 |      420450 |              4 | 2014-04-14 09:16:49 |    Hot |
| 422933 |      420451 |             37 | 2014-04-14 09:18:41 |    Hot |
| 422938 |      420452 |              1 | 2014-04-10 20:50:30 |    Hot |
| 422984 |      420452 |              1 | 2014-04-12 20:50:30 |   Warm |
| 422940 |      420453 |             47 | 2014-04-14 09:20:27 |    Hot |
+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+--------+
```

## EDIT

To answer some of the possibilities about nulls:

`select count(id) from customers_history where customer_id is null`: 0

`select count(id) from customers_history where lead_source_id is null`: 5103

`select count(id) from customers_history where repurchased_date is null`: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious conclusion is that some `lead_source_id`s share values of `repurchased_date`.

Another possibility is that you have `NULL` values for `customer_id` and the second filters these out.

The third possibility is that `NULL` values of `lead_source_id` are adding additional values in the first query.

Comment: see the update about nulls. I think the problem is the first item you mentioned, how can we fix that?

Comment: @exabrial . . . count them the first way because that produces the correct result.

Comment: +1 Gordon nailed it. The inline view in the second query is returning a unique set of `customer_id` values from the same rows that are being returned by the outer query (because it's the same table and same predicates). So, the predicate in the `ON` clause is effectively the same as specifying **`customer_id IS NOT NULL`**, and given there aren't any NULL values for **`customer_id`**, adding the JOIN to the inline view doesn't change the resultset. Note that **`DISTINCT`** is a keyword, and applies to the entire set of expressions in the SELECT list, so no need for parens around `customer_id`.